# SharePoint Framework documentation propertyPaneConfiguration

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

I'm finally getting around to looking at the SharePoint Framework again (working on it in my few spare cycles when I don't have client work). The [documentation says](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part) "Replace the propertyPaneConfiguration method with the code below which adds the new property pane fields and maps them to their respective typed objects." I replaced the code as instructed and I get an error "Cannot find name IPropertyPaneConfiguration" and "Return type of public property getter from exported class has or is using private name IPropertyPaneConfiguration" on the line:

```
protected get propertyPaneConfiguration(): IPropertyPaneConfiguration {
```

Should that read

```
protected get propertyPaneSettings(): IPropertyPaneSettings {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should be

```
protected get propertyPaneSettings(): IPropertyPaneSettings
```

Looks like the documentation is incorrect.  I'll log a bug to fix it.